# primefaces autocomplete not showing in textBox

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have tried to implement the autocomplete feature in primefaces but suggestions do not show up in my textbox. Can someone show me what I'm missing. theses are codes

udateCategory.xhtml

---

```
<p:panel header="Type in Category to Edit" >                
    <p:outputLabel value="Category Name"/> 
    <p:autoComplete value="#{categoryBean.selectedCategory}" 
                                     completeMethod="#{categoryBean.completeCategory}"
                                     var="cat"
                                     itemLabel="#{cat.categoryName}"
                                     itemValue="#{cat}"
                                     converter="#{catConverter}"
                                     forceSelection="true"/>


     <p:commandButton value="Update" action="#{category.saveCategory}"/>
</p:panel>
```

CategoryBean

---

```
public class CategoryBean implements Serializable{

    private Category selectedCategory;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of CategoryBean
     */
    public CategoryBean() {
    }

    public List<Category> completeCategory (String query){

        CategoryManager manager  =  new CategoryManager();//an instance of the manager
        List<Category> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();//an instance of list
        List<Category> allCategory = new ArrayList<>(); //populate the allCategory with data fro db
        allCategory = manager.getAllCategory();

        //checck to see if data exist in allCategory
        if(!allCategory.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("kobla : allcategory has data");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("kobla: no data in alcategory");
        }

        for(Category cat : allCategory){
            if(cat.getCategoryName().startsWith(query)){
                suggestions.add(cat);
            }
        }

        //check to see if data exists in sugestions
        if (!suggestions.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("kobla : suggestions has data");
        } else {
            System.out.println("kobla: no data in suggestions");
        }
        return suggestions;
    }



    /**
     * @return the selectedCategory
     */
    public Category getSelectedCategory() {
        return selectedCategory;
    }

    /**
     * @param selectedCategory the selectedCategory to set
     */
    public void setSelectedCategory(Category selectedCategory) {
        this.selectedCategory = selectedCategory;
    }


}
```

CategoryConverter

---

```
public class CategoryConverter implements Converter{ 

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

        if(value.trim().equals("")){
            return null;
        }
        else{
        try{
            int id = Integer.parseInt(value);
            List<Category> myCategory = new ArrayList<>();//
            myCategory = new CategoryManager().getAllCategory();//load data fro db
            for(Category cat : myCategory){
                if(cat.getCategoryID() == id){
                    return cat;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        return  null;
    }



    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {

        if(value == null || value ==""){
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return String.valueOf(((Category)value).getCategoryName());
        }
      //  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CategoryBean implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Category selectedCategory;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        selectedCategory = new Category();
    }

    public void saveCategory(){
        System.out.println("saved "+this.selectedCategory);
    }

    public List<Category> completeCategory(String query) {
        CategoryManager manager = new CategoryManager();// an instance of the
                                                        // manager
        List<Category> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();// an instance of list
        List<Category> allCategory = new ArrayList<>(); // populate the
                                                        // allCategory with data
                                                        // fro db
        allCategory = manager.getAllCategory();

        // checck to see if data exist in allCategory
        if (!allCategory.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("kobla : allcategory has data");
        } else {
            System.out.println("kobla: no data in alcategory");
        }

        for (Category cat : allCategory) {
            if (cat.getCategoryName().startsWith(query)) {
                suggestions.add(cat);
            }
        }

        // check to see if data exists in sugestions
        if (!suggestions.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("kobla : suggestions has data");
        } else {
            System.out.println("kobla: no data in suggestions");
        }
        return suggestions;
    }

    /**
     * @return the selectedCategory
     */
    public Category getSelectedCategory() {
        return selectedCategory;
    }

    /**
     * @param selectedCategory
     *            the selectedCategory to set
     */
    public void setSelectedCategory(Category selectedCategory) {
        this.selectedCategory = selectedCategory;
    }

}
```

and

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Category implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int categoryID;
    private String categoryName;
    public int getCategoryID() {
        return categoryID;
    }
    public void setCategoryID(int categoryID) {
        this.categoryID = categoryID;
    }
    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }
    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }
    public Category(int categoryID, String categoryName) {
        super();
        this.categoryID = categoryID;
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }
    public Category() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category [categoryID=" + categoryID + ", categoryName="
                + categoryName + "]";
    }

}
```

and

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class CategoryConverter implements Converter, Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

        if(value.trim().equals("")){
            return null;
        }
        else{
        try{
            int id = Integer.parseInt(value);
            List<Category> myCategory = new ArrayList<>();//
            myCategory = new CategoryManager().getAllCategory();//load data fro db
            for(Category cat : myCategory){
                if(cat.getCategoryID() == id){
                    return cat;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        return  null;
    }



    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {

        if(value == null || value ==""){
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return String.valueOf(((Category)value).getCategoryName());
        }
      //  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:outputLabel value="Category Name" />
        <p:autoComplete 
            value="#{categoryBean.selectedCategory}"
            completeMethod="#{categoryBean.completeCategory}" 
            var="cat"
            itemLabel="#{cat.categoryName}" 
            itemValue="#{cat}"
            converter="#{categoryConverter}" 
            forceSelection="true" />
        <p:commandButton value="Update" action="#{categoryBean.saveCategory}" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've done all the changes but it's not helping. It's the same story.I also realized that the arrayList "suggestions " has no data in it.

Comment: I´ve run this code on tomee 1.6.0+ with java 7. In my example, if you type "T" it suggests "Two" and "Three" as expected. What container and JSF version are you using? Have you tried to just copy and paste this code into your app?